# CSS !important IE8 not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, background-color

***Mistyped code. Fix found***

*.tblmain td overrides an tr affects due to the DOM level. .tblmain tr should be used instead. If anyone wants to submit as an answer, I will accept. Thank you!*

I am using the `!important` identifier in my CSS to be certain the background color of a `tr` is changed on hover.

The CSS for the `tr` is

```
.tblmain td {
    background-color: white;
}
```

then through a `onmouseover` event I use javascript as below

```
onmouseover='$(this).addClass("hover")'
```

the hover css is below

```
.hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #15b6b8 !important;
}
```

The background is still white on hover, but when the `tr` class is remove, the hover works as expected. I know `!important` is considered hacky in situations like these, so I am open to any suggestions including but not limited to using `!important` to make the predominant color the hover class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use firebug to see who sets the background and also not sure $(this) points to anything , onmouseover isn't used in ages

Comment: for what you need javascript at all? What is wrong with `.tblmain tr:hover` for a simple colorchange on hover?

Comment: you could do `.tblmain tr.hover` instead of using `!important`

Comment: @SvenBieder Does IE8 support `:hover` on tr's? (i can't remember anymore)

Comment: @KevinB As long as you have a valid doctype IE8 should make no problems with the hover.

Comment: @KevinB [It's a CSS 2.1 selector](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2)

Comment: @SvenBieder We originally coded this in IE7, then updated to IE8 on a company level after it was in production. The changes I'm adding don't use :hover because of that. Changing them would be a large-scale change I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: @max4ever is there a way to do this without firebug? We do not have firebug in our production system and there is a lengthy approval process for programs not pre-approved.

Comment: Just use Firefox's or IE's or Chrome's built-in DOM debugger, then.

Comment: It's funny how `!` in a lot of languages means `NOT`. So, !important could be read as `NOT Important`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're adding a class, but not removing it? Use `toggleClass` instead.

Further, using `onmouseover` is poor separation of code. Try this:

```
$('.tblmain').on('mouseover mouseout', 'tr', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

You might need to toggle the background-color of the `td` children instead, though. If there is a background-color applied to those, it can and will override the styles for the `tr`.

```
$('.tblmain').on('mouseover mouseout', 'tr', function(e) {
    $(this).find('td').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: I remove the class using .removeClass("hover") on mouse out. I didn't include that portion because I didn't see it to be relevant to the issue at hand. That is covered though.

Comment: Well, there should be no problem that I can see. Try creating a self-contained instance on http://jsfiddle.net or use your browser's DOM browser to examine the CSS and find out why it's not being applied as expected.